# non-overlapping positive look-behind assertion

Tags: python, regex

I am searching for a given pattern in a string, and I don't want finditer to return the first position of the match but a given position in the match. Both the pattern and the position to be returned can vary.
For example a pattern can be 'ATTAAT' and in this case I want finditer to return the second position of the match.
The simple way to do it is just to add 2 to whatever position I get:

```
import re
seq = 'GGGGATTAATCCCATTAATTAATCCC'
for m in re.finditer('ATTAAT', seq):
    print m.start() + 2
```

This returns the position 6 and 15, and it is perfectly fine.

But my problem is that I need to search for several patterns at the same time (e.g. ATTAAT and GATC) and for each of these pattern I would need to return a different relative position (for instance in the first case I would need to return the position +2, and in the second, the position +1).

I found that this could be solved by using positive look-behind assertion, and writing something like:

```
re.finditer('((?<=AT)TAAT)|((?<=G)ATC)', seq))
```

The problem is that if I apply it on my (simpler) first example, I got a different result:

```
import re
seq = 'GGGGATTAATCCCATTAATTAATCCC'
for m in re.finditer('(?<=AT)TAAT', seq):
    print m.start()
```

This finds me a match in positions 6, 15 **and 19**. I assume that this is because finditer does not consume the same amount of characters because of the look-behind assertion.

In order to solve this issue, I could parse my array of results and remove the ones that are overlapping, but it seems very inefficient, and I was wondering if someone had a better idea... even using a completely different strategy.

---

**EDIT**

I found a solution using regex:

```
import re
seq = 'GGGGATTAATCCCATTAATTAATCCC'
for m in re.finditer('(AT)(TAAT)', seq):
    print m.start(2)
```

I preferred using look-behind assertion, but I still don't know how to make finditer to consume the full string.

Comment: "even using a completely different strategy." I don't know exactly what it is you're trying to do in the long-run but I'm taking a stab at the fact this is some kind of DNA sequence and there are libraries for this e.g. [biopython](http://biopython.org/wiki/Documentation). That might not do what you need but since you haven't explained why this can't be done with existing packages I do wonder whether you've exhausted the google-search approach for pre-made packages?

Comment: Hi @roganjosh , I didn't wanted to make my question too specific. And yes, what I want to do can be done using biopython (http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/cookbook/Restriction.html#2) but (in this case) I have the feeling that it can be improved, as what they do is to repeat the search for each input pattern. And I am also just curious about different ways to solve it (and about why finditer does not consume all the characters with the positive look-behind assertion). thanks

Comment: Are different search patterns allowed to overlap *each other*?

Comment: good point @glibdud, I haven't thought about this yet. Ideally yes, I would allow them to overlap. thanks

Comment: @fransua In that case, I don't think you're going to be able to do this in a single pass. I won't say it's not possible, but if it is, it would probably involve some *really* ugly regex hackery.

Comment: @glibdud , you're right, and I guess the biopython solution is probably the best. thanks